# How to compute different ranges of quantiles of columns in a dataframe based on percentage of missing values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to compute the quantiles of columns A and B from dataframe df but I would like to calculate different quantiles according to the percentage of missing value of these columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice', NA, NA, NA, 'Rob', 'Max'], 
                   'B': ['Example', NA, NA, 'Test', 'Check', NA, NA, NA]})
```

Additionally, since A and B are in character format, I would like to first count the length of each row for every column so that

```
df_count = pd.DataFrame({'A': [3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3], 
                       'B': [7, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0]})
```

and only then compute the quantiles on the new values of A and B according to the percentage of missing values.

For example, if the percentage of missing values of column A is greater than 90%, then I would like to compute the quantile(0.99), else if the percentage of missing values of column A is less than 90%, I would like to compute the quantile(0.10).

As a final step, I would write the values of the quantiles in a new dataframe:

```
df_quant = pd.DataFrame({'A_quant': [quantile_value_for_A], 
                       'B_quant': [quantile_value_for_B]})
```

Is there a way to do this? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Super, can you add expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice', np.nan,np.nan, np.nan, 'Rob', 'Max'], 
                   'B': ['Example', np.nan, np.nan, 'Test', 'Check', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

df_count = pd.DataFrame({'A': [3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3], 
                       'B': [7, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0]})
```

---

```
#get percentage of NaNs
print (df.isna().mean())
A    0.375
B    0.625
dtype: float64

#compare by threshold, here 0.5 for test, with real data change to 0.9
thresh = .5
m = df.isna().mean() > thresh
print (m)
A    False
B     True
dtype: bool

#count both percentile
a = df_count.quantile(0.9999)
print (a)
A    4.9993
B    6.9986
Name: 0.9999, dtype: float64

b = df_count.quantile(0.999)
print (b)
A    4.993
B    6.986
Name: 0.999, dtype: float64

#set values by mask
out = np.where(m, a, b)
print (out)
[4.993  6.9986]
```

---

```
#create DataFrame
df_quant = pd.DataFrame([out], columns= m.index).add_suffix('_quant')
print (df_quant)
   A_quant  B_quant
0    4.993   6.9986
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I wanted! How would you write the code if df has more than 2 columns? Let's say 100?

Comment: @inegue - exactly same way, there are not specified columns, so it count all columns.